# Set a separate folder in published directory for referenced projects in VS 2017 for MVC5.0 web application

Tags: c#, build, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have created a common project that I need for all of my development work, this project uses `"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"` version `5.1.4 (>=)` since I'm using lots of it JSON Web token functions [such as `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to create/verify web tokens].

In my main project, I had to recently add `ADFS` authentication, but I couldn't use the same version of `"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"`, since `OWIN (3.1.0.0)` has issues (issues on [github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3017)). So I had to downgrade the `"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"` to `version ="4.0.40306.1554"` in the main project while in the common project it is using 5.x.x.x.

Now when I publish my solution it always replaces `"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"` with the `version ="4.0.40306.1554"` and when I try parsing I keep getting

```
Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' from
assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

when I try the following

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
     Wtrealm = realm,
     MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
     SignOutWreply = adfsSignOut,
     Wreply = externalLoginCallback,
     AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
     BackchannelCertificateValidator = null,
});
```

Now I have tried `CodeBase` version to set dll load to try to load two versions of DLL but no luck. Also `<probing privatePath="bin/JWT5.1.4"/>` didn't resolved my issue. Now my question,

1. Is there any way that I can tell VS 2017 that when it publishes, put everything including dll references in `common` project in `common` directory
2. In the JWT utility class in `Common` project, can I tell it to go look for `Common` directory if there is missing assembly exception?

Thanks in advance.